# periodically_call_remote: Rails AJAX for a facebook app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, facebook, prototypejs

i'm building a RoR app for facebook using FBML and the Prototype JavaScript library.

what i'm trying to do is have a div automatically refreshed, using the neat 
`periodically_call_remote`, which creates a [PeriodicalExecuter](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/periodicalExecuter) object.

here's the code:

```
 <%= render :partial => "status_item", :collection => @status %>
 <%= periodically_call_remote( :url => { :action => :status, :id => @hunt.id }, :update => 'status_div') %>
```

i'm getting 2 kinds of errors:

1. `SyntaxError: Parse error`'s on fbml_static_get.php on http://biascica.pipps.net:8888/javascripts/prototype.js?1246455754 and the likes (effects.js and controls.js)
2. `ReferenceError`'s: `can't find variable a116508001384_PeriodicalExecuter`

this is the javascript code, as modified by facebook:

```
new a116508001384_PeriodicalExecuter(function() {new a116508001384_Ajax.Updater('status_div', '/corinna_test/servers/ren%C3%A9/treasure_hunts/12/status', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'authenticity_token=' + a116508001384_encodeURIComponent('qBY5jTvJ04rEcvLsQzkhNkEhRXN1wRA2ITrgq/4JmVg=')})}, 10)
```

(notice how they appended `a116508001384_` in front of almost everything)

i'm also getting `iframex` errors but i don't think that's a priority right now.

can anyone help me make sense of this mess?

thanks!
asymmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. Facebook has its own restricted version of Javascript called Facebook Javascript ([FBJS](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS)). You need to use Facebook's Ajax object. The prototype API stuff won't work with FBJS. You need to use FBJS or put your application in an iframe.

```
function doAjaxStuff() {
    var ajax = new Ajax();
    var params = { param1: 'param1' };
    ajax.responseType = Ajax.FBML;
    ajax.ondone = function(data) { $('div').setInnerFBML(data); };
    ajax.onerror = function() { $('div').setTextValue('error...'); };
    ajax.post(URL, params); 
}
```